# Apache Whitelisting IPaddress To Access Website

Tags: apache, ip-restrictions

My requirement is to allow my website to be accessed only through the whitelisted ips.
What did I do is, as I'm on apache version (Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)) I had added below block to apache_inbound.conf
As I'm on VPN I've got the ip address from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and https://ifconfig.me/ip but still I'm been restricted and getting below error message.

In the Apache logs I see something as 'source' and client' ips. Source ip is one which I'm getting from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ n whitelisting this is not working. However when I whitelist 'client' ip it is working but i see the client ip of my laptop n mobile are same(my mobile is running on mobile data only)

I suspect that whitelisting is working but I'm not getting the correct ip to do or I'm commuting some mistake here.

can someone please help me to fix this issue?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   Require ip a.b.c.d
</VirtualHost>
```

Error message:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: it seems a review on how tcp/ip works is required. tldr that apache rule applies to immediate ip address. try use php or something to echo back your ip address as seen by your web server.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand you @BagusTesa -can someone help?